# Webscraping on attachments

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

Hello I'm trying to download files from a site and save all files into specific folder.

Below are the steps that i need.

1. Navigate with the sites/links provided in column A one by one
2. Download all files related to each site/link to specified path of column B.
3. There may be attachments 1 or 2 or more then 10 etc. or some times there may not have attachments. (FYI)

I prepared code for this but this is pulling only names of the files but not the content...that was failed.  im still struggling to find result...

```
Sub AP()
Dim IE As New InternetExplorer, html As HTMLDocument
Dim elem As Object, data As String
With IE
    .Visible = True
    .navigate "https://www.MyURL.com"
    Do While .readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE: Loop
    Set html = .document
End With
data = ""
For Each elem In html.getElementsByClassName("pull-right")(0) _
.getElementsByTagName("a")
    data = data & " " & elem.innerText
Next elem
Range("A1").Value = data

IE.Quit
```

End Sub

Any help.. Thanks

Comment: You missed to add the VBA code you have tried. Please [edit] your question and add your code. Please also add a question, you didn't ask one yet.

Comment: PEH, that code is not working accurately and that i have stated in the post.

Comment: But we can only tell what you did wrong if you show us what exactly you did and tell us where in your code you got errors. Otherwise we cannot help you. So please provide your code (see [ask]).

Comment: I have copied my code in the post. Thanks

Comment: Check the network tab when manually downloading to see if there are XHR requests you can mimic to download the files without using IE. IE is a pain for downloading files to a specific folder/ any folder. Otherwise, use selenium where you can configure download directory.

Comment: Thank you QHarr,  I heard many time about this selenium. But I  don't have any knowledge about selenium. I already requested my IT team to have this exe file in my system.. kindly can you share me code with selenium.. so that I will work with that code once I have the application in my system..  Thanks for your valuable reply... QHarr, One thing I want to ask you.. I want to gain knowledge in programming like you. can you guide me in that, I saw many of your valuable post in this forum those are very knowledgeable.. that's the reason I'm asking.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this and feedback?

```
Sub TryMe()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim FileNum As Long
    Dim FileData() As Byte
    Dim MyFile As String
    Dim WHTTP As Object
    Dim lrow As Long
    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet

    On Error Resume Next
        Set WHTTP = CreateObject("WinHTTP.WinHTTPrequest.5")
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            Set WHTTP = CreateObject("WinHTTP.WinHTTPrequest.5.1")
        End If
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Dir("C:\MyDownloads", vbDirectory) = Empty Then MkDir "C:\MyDownloads"

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        For lrow = 1 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            MyFile = Cells(lrow, 1).Text
            TempFile = Right(MyFile, InStr(1, StrReverse(MyFile), "/") - 1)
            WHTTP.Open "GET", MyFile, False
            WHTTP.Send
            FileData = WHTTP.ResponseBody

            FileNum = FreeFile
            Open "C:\MyDownloads\" & TempFile For Binary Access Write As #FileNum
                Put #FileNum, 1, FileData
            Close #FileNum
            DoEvents
        Next lrow
    End With

    Set WHTTP = Nothing
    MsgBox "Open the folder [ C:\MyDownloads ] for the downloaded file..."
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Hello ASH, first of all thanks for your response, im getting this msg "Run time error '52': Bad file name or number" when i execute the file at open code line. i have copied the screenshot for your reference. Do i need to select any references in tools in the VBA code. Please advise. Thanks

Comment: This is designed to run on your desktop.  The code works fine for me.  What line throws the error?  Is it this line?
Open "C:\MyDownloads\" & TempFile

Comment: It's best to hit the F8 key over and over and over, to step through the code, line by line, and see what's causing the error.

Comment: ASH, Yes, The line "Open "C:\MyDownloads\" & TempFile For Binary Access Write As #FileNum" is showing the above screenshot error message.  I ran the code using F8 to understand line by line...

Comment: Ok, so Google that specific error.  I did, and I found this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/bad-file-name-or-number-error-52